# C# .net casting question

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a bit confused about the following.

Given this class:

```
    public class SomeClassToBeCasted
    {
        public static implicit operator string(SomeClassToBeCasted rightSide)
        {
            return rightSide.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Why is an InvalidCastException thrown when I try to do the following?

```
IList<SomeClassToBeCasted> someClassToBeCastedList 
     = new List<SomeClassToBeCasted> {new SomeClassToBeCasted()};
IEnumerable<string> results = someClassToBeCastedList.Cast<string>();

foreach (var item in results)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `Cast()` doesn't deal with user-specified casts - only reference conversions (i.e. the normal sort of conversion of a reference up or down the inheritance hierarchy) and boxing/unboxing conversions. It's not the same as what a cast will do in source code. Unfortunately this isn't clearly documented :(

EDIT: Just to bring Jason's comment into the post, you can work around this easily with a projection:

```
IEnumerable<string> results = originalList.Select(x => (string) x);
```

Comment: And, to add, you can get "around" this with `IEnumerable<string> results = someClassToBeCastedList.Select(x => (string)x);`

Answer (score 6):

If only needed for lists, you can do

```
IEnumerable<string> results =
        someClassToBeCastedList.Select(itm => itm.ToString());
```

instead.

Comment: This doesn't even use the user-defined cast that the OP defined.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant about the lists. It depends on if that cast operator functionality is needed in other places too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this i to got similar problem it will helps you

> IEnumerable results = originalList.Select(x => (string) x);